# Second Hardware RAID 1 drive not mounted with correct size

Tags: hard-drive, raid, dmraid

My set-up is the following:

- **Hardware**

  - **Mainboard**: `Supermicro X9DRi-F`
  - **Hardware-RAID-Controller** (onboard)
  - **HDs**:
  - HD0, HD1: 2TB
  - HD2, HD3: 6TB
  - **RAID-Devices**:
  - `raidvol1`: HD0 + HD1 in RAID1 (*working*)
  - `raidvol2`: HD2 + HD3 in RAID1 (*not working*)
- **Software**

  - **Ubuntu**: `Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS`
  - **Kernel**: `Linux donny 3.13.0-105-generic #152-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 2 15:37:11 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
  - **dmraid version**: `1.0.0.rc16 (2009.09.16) shared`
  - **dmraid library version**: `1.0.0.rc16 (2009.09.16)`
  - **device-mapper version**: `unknown`

**Screenshots of RAID controller UI**

1. [This one shows the RAID controller UI when creating the new volume.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U48QT.png)
2. [This one shows the RAID controller UI after the new volume is created. Both volume are available and the references to the harddrives are correct.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weSDj.png)

**Output of `lsblk` when the system is up and running**

```
NAME                                           MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO
TYPE   MOUNTPOINT
sda                                              8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk 
└─isw_faceeabfg_raidvol1 (dm-0)                252:0    0   1.7T  0 dmraid
  ├─isw_faceeabfg_raidvol1p1 (dm-2)            252:2    0 243.1M  0 part   /boot
  ├─isw_faceeabfg_raidvol1p2 (dm-3)            252:3    0     1K  0 part 
  └─isw_faceeabfg_raidvol1p5 (dm-4)            252:4    0   1.7T  0 part 
    ├─vg--donny--disc--0--1-lv--system (dm-5)  252:5    0 247.4G  0 lvm    /
    ├─vg--donny--disc--0--1-lv--swap (dm-6)    252:6    0    32G  0 lvm    [SWAP]
    └─vg--donny--disc--0--1-lv--storage (dm-7) 252:7    0     1T  0 lvm    /srv/storage
sdb                                              8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk 
└─isw_faceeabfg_raidvol1 (dm-0)                252:0    0   1.7T  0 dmraid
  ├─isw_faceeabfg_raidvol1p1 (dm-2)            252:2    0 243.1M  0 part   /boot
  ├─isw_faceeabfg_raidvol1p2 (dm-3)            252:3    0     1K  0 part 
  └─isw_faceeabfg_raidvol1p5 (dm-4)            252:4    0   1.7T  0 part 
    ├─vg--donny--disc--0--1-lv--system (dm-5)  252:5    0 247.4G  0 lvm    /
    ├─vg--donny--disc--0--1-lv--swap (dm-6)    252:6    0    32G  0 lvm    [SWAP]
    └─vg--donny--disc--0--1-lv--storage (dm-7) 252:7    0     1T  0 lvm    /srv/storage
sdc                                              8:32   0   5.5T  0 disk 
└─isw_hefagdhbe_raidvol2 (dm-1)                252:1    0   1.2T  0 dmraid
sdd                                              8:48   0   5.5T  0 disk 
└─isw_hefagdhbe_raidvol2 (dm-1)                252:1    0   1.2T  0 dmraid
```

The last part shows the problem:

```
sdc                                              8:32   0   5.5T  0 disk 
└─isw_hefagdhbe_raidvol2 (dm-1)                252:1    0   1.2T  0 dmraid
sdd                                              8:48   0   5.5T  0 disk 
└─isw_hefagdhbe_raidvol2 (dm-1)                252:1    0   1.2T  0 dmraid
```

The device size is correct with `5.5T` but the `raidvol2` is limited to `1.2T`.

- What can I do to get the `raidvol1` with the correct size?
- Do you need any additional information from my side?

Comment: Hi and welcome to AskUbuntu! Thank you for taking the time to write a high-quality question!

Comment: My current workaround is using a dmraid and mdadm raid at the same time. Working but not elegant.